# Finding a div tag by attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have some div tags, and I added a number of attributes to each one of them:

```
<div class='item' number='1'></div>
<div class='item' number='2'></div>
<div class='item' number='3'></div>
```

When I try this in the console

```
$("div[number=2 ]")
```

it gives me the right div, but I want to do this:

```
 var number = $( 'div#stick span' ).attr('number'); //I want to get the number dynamically.
 $("div['number'=number ]")
```

It doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: I know you have an answer but you should really use the [html5 data attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html) to store your custom data and use the jQuery [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)  method to retrieve the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var number = $( 'div#stick span' ).attr('number'); //I want to get the number dynamically.
$("div[number="+number+" ]");
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$("div[number='"+number+"']")
```

OR

```
$("div[number='2']")
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/VY7rv/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var number = $( 'div#stick span' ).attr('number'); //I want to get the number dynamically.
var $('div[number="'+number+'"]'); // Your element
```

Remember [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) gets the object using the queryselector of [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). The way to make the selector by attribute is yourelement[property="value"], like [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets).